# cursor.getCount always = 0

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, cursor

I need to implement an algorithm that access to the database to check the last elemnt in order to calculate the new one. Of course, the first time it would be impossible because the database is empty and I get

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException) index 0 requested with a size of 0
```

To avoid it, I tried to check if `cursor.getCount==0`, and then I introduce a default first element. The problem is that, even when I have stored it in the database, `cursor.getCount` keeps being `0`. Here is the code of my method:

```
public Measures getLastMeasure(String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEASURES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_DATE, KEY_TIME_HOUR, KEY_TIME_MINUTE, KEY_BE_INTAKE,
            KEY_GLUCOSE, KEY_BOLUS, KEY_BASAL }, KEY_DATE + "=?",
            new String[] { date }, null, null, KEY_TIME_HOUR + " DESC, "
                    + KEY_TIME_MINUTE + " DESC", "1");
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Measures m = new Measures("nodate", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return m;
    } else {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Measures m = new Measures(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0)), // id
                cursor.getString(1), // date
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), // timeHour
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)), // timeMinute
                Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)), // BE intake
                Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(5)), // glucose
                Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(6)), // bolus
                Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(7)) // basal

        );
        // return m
        return m;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: If you have data in your database and the cursor is always returning 0 rows, maybe your `KEY_DATE + "=?"` filter is not doing what you are expecting it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something, but that code looks correct to me. Are you certain that the data you're looking for is actually in the database and that the argument you're passing to getLastMeasure() is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query returns no data matching your search. If you only want latest data by date, I suggest `order by KEY_DATE desc` and `limit 1`, or `max(KEY_DATE)` instead of `KEY_DATE + "=?"`

Side note: no need to check if `cursor` is `null` (`SQLiteDatabase#query` never returns a null `Cursor`), and anyway your check is useless because you're accessing `cursor` even if it's `null`. Also you're not closing the `Cursor`.

Comment: By the way, the method max() doesn't exist

Comment: Close the cursor before returning from the method. This is why I also prefer having only one return in this kind of method. You can modify your code to have the extact same behavior with only one return statement (also usually having only one return statement makes the method more readable, because the exit point is only one). I mean [SQLite max() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Comment: And how can I call that function? I closed the cursor but it still doesnt' work.

Comment: Closing the cursor does not solve your current problem. It's to avoid memory leaks. I don't know if you can use `max()` with that query method, you can try the other solution I suggest first.